# Lag Partition equivalent MS Access

Tags: ms-access

I am looking for equivalent of following Oracle query in MS Access. I know that Lag Over (Partition by ) function is not available in MS Access but looking for to acheive same functionality of below query using MS Access.. Appreciate any inputs

```
select  t.*,
to_char(date1,'yyyymm') month,
lag(value1,1,0) over(partition by Id1,name1,office,product,overall order by date1)    prev_val
from  test_prev t
order by name1,
office,
overall,
date1,
product
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Working from the [Oracle example](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/lag.php) and considering your query, you may find a subquery would suit. If not, a User Defined Function would be a possibility.

This returns the previous order date by product_id

```
SELECT Orders.ORDER_DATE, 
       Orders.PRODUCT_ID, 
       Orders.QTY, 
      (SELECT Top 1 o.Order_Date 
       FROM Orders o 
       WHERE o.Order_Date<Orders.Order_Date 
       AND o.Product_ID=Orders.Product_ID 
       ORDER BY o.Order_Date DESC) AS PreviousOrder
FROM Orders
ORDER BY Orders.ORDER_DATE, Orders.PRODUCT_ID
```

In the sample data, each product_id has a different date for each order, so a subquery with ORDER BY date alone is sufficient, however, Top queries in Access return matches, so if duplicates are a possibility, it is best to order by the relevant field and a unique id.

Answer (score 0):

something like this:

```
SELECT p4.*, p5.qty AS qtyNext
FROM (
SELECT p1.ID, p1.qty,
(SELECT MAX(p3.price) FROM myTbl p3 WHERE p3.price < p1.price) AS prev_price, 
p1.price AS current_rec, 
(SELECT MIN(p2.price) FROM myTbl p2 WHERE p2.price > p1.price) AS next_price
FROM myTbl AS p1 
) AS p4
INNER JOIN myTbl AS p5 
ON p4.next_price=p5.price;
```

but look if such representation of output suits you (- if prices have duplicates - all records appear to get to output)...