# Trouble with filling a column with values from a set of two values depending on the difference between consecutive rows

Tags: sql, ms-access

I've got a frustrating trouble which I would like to show on an example

Table(ID,Name,Subname,ID2,Score)

```
ID  Name   Subname ID2 Score

1    A     A87564   1    <
2    A     A87564   2    <
3    A     A87564   3    <
4    A     A78564   1    >
5    A     A78564   2    >
6    B     B23456   1    <
7    B     B23456   2    <
8    B     B32456   1    >
9    B     B32456   2    >
5    B     B32456   3    >
6    C     C89004   1    <
..........................
..........................
```

There are always two different subnames for each name but the number of rows having the same subname is NOT constant. I wrote the set of figures in Subname cells intentionally to show how it varies between the rows having the same name. As you can see the last three figures are the same for each name, two first figures change place.

I've managed to fill the ID2 column using

`( SELECT COUNT(T2.Subname)
            FROM Table AS T2
            WHERE T2.ID <= T.ID 
            AND T.Subname = T2.Subname )
            AS ID2`

But I'm totally stucked on trying to assign the '<' or '>' icons depending on Subname or ID2 change between consecutive rows. It doesn't matter which of these icons will be assigned. The only condition is that it should change between subnames of the same Name.

I was trying to fix it using many sql tools and functions, using ID2 difference or even trying to base on subnames literals difference.

If you have any ideas that could help me, please let me know.

Comment: It sounds as if you are looking for an ms-access equivalent if LAG. See in this article if it helps:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12084963/lag-partition-equivalent-ms-access

Comment: The sample data in your question suggests that the [ID] column is not filled with unique values. Is that really the case, or is that just a copy/paste artifact?

Answer (score -1):

It can almost definitely be done with subqueries, (have your working query as a subquery say "current" and join it with itself ("previous"), and comparing a row's value to the value in a row with max(previous.identifier) less than current.identifier) but this might be a case where mysql inline variables are going to make it slightly more readable and more performant. So here is an imperfect start:

```
select ID,Name,Subname,ID2,
  if( @lastSubname = Subname or @lastSubname="", @flip, @flop ) as Score,
  if (@lastSubname = Subname or @lastSubname="", @temp:="", @temp:=@flip) as a,
  if (@lastSubname = Subname or @lastSubname="", @temp:="", @flip:=@flop) as b,
  if (@lastSubname = Subname or @lastSubname="", @temp:="", @flop:=@temp) as c,
  @lastSubname:=Subname
from t1, ( select @lastSubname := "", @flip :="<", @flop :=">" , @temp:="") Vars
order by Subname
```

Where the `select @lastSubname...` initialises the variables, and you update it at the "end" of each row (after the check you need to do). `flip` and `flop` are swapped when you change value. There may easily be a neater way to do this... I was playing [here on sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2571f/22).

Comment: My answer feels like a bit of a hack. Comments welcome on other approaches. :)