# SQL Query create a Last Date column from a Date column

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am working in MS Access. I have a table essentially with products and their ship dates. I want to add a new column with the "Last Shipped" date for the product.

To illustrate, say I start with these records:

| Product | ShipDate |
| --- | --- |
| 1-110 | 04/15/23 |
| 1-110 | 01/31/23 |
| 1-110 | 10/18/22 |
| 1-111 | 09/25/23 |
| 1-111 | 12/13/22 |
| 1-112 | 10/15/23 |

At the end, I want to have these records:

| Product | ShipDate | LastShipped |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1-110 | 04/15/23 | 01/31/23 |
| 1-110 | 01/31/23 | 10/18/22 |
| 1-111 | 09/25/23 | 12/13/22 |

What is an efficient way to do this?

I've tried out a query to join the table to itself on product, ShipDate from table1 and ShipDate from table2 where table2<table1. This works pretty fast, but leaves me extra records I need to prune (e.g. prod 1-110 shipdate 4/15/23 would become two records, with 'lastshipped' 1/31/23 AND 10/18/22).

```
SELECT table1.Product, table1.ShipDate, table2.ShipDate AS LastShipped

FROM table1 INNER JOIN table1 AS table2 ON (table1.Product = table2.Product)

WHERE table2.LastShipped < table1.ShipDate
```

Trying to do a MAX(table2.shipdate) just screws me over in query run time, and when the query finally finishes it gives me 0 records anyways.

```
SELECT table1.Product, table1.ShipDate, Max(table2.ShipDate) AS LastShipped

FROM table1 INNER JOIN table1 AS table2 ON (table1.Product = table2.Product)

GROUP BY table1.Product, table1.ShipDate

HAVING table2.LastShipped < table1.ShipDate
```

Any help or advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you put the exact queries you've tried? If a simple max() is too costly your data might be large enough that Access is not the tool for the job. Might be something causing that to blow up.

Comment: Try referring to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64227887/lag-function-in-microsoft-access-window-function . Most more sophisticated databases than Access support a function for LAG() which does exactly this (hint: filter out NULL rows from the derived column). That answer has how to do the equivalent in Access with a correlated subquery.

Comment: The LAG() comment is great, learn something new every day, but the specific link did not work out. I did do some searching for LAG posts, and this answer was very relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12084963/lag-partition-equivalent-ms-access

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Access doesn't support lag, you have to work around it. Your first query is actually very close, just needs another step to get the latest out of your "extra" records.

Postgres fiddle (should work for Access): https://dbfiddle.uk/IySL-C37

```
create table Orders 
  ( product varchar(255),
    shipDate date
  );

-- Assuming you have a table named 'Orders' with columns 'Product' and 'ShipDate'
INSERT INTO Orders (Product, ShipDate) VALUES ('1-110', '2023-04-15');
INSERT INTO Orders (Product, ShipDate) VALUES ('1-110', '2023-01-31');
INSERT INTO Orders (Product, ShipDate) VALUES ('1-110', '2022-10-18');
INSERT INTO Orders (Product, ShipDate) VALUES ('1-111', '2023-09-25');
INSERT INTO Orders (Product, ShipDate) VALUES ('1-111', '2022-12-13');
INSERT INTO Orders (Product, ShipDate) VALUES ('1-112', '2023-10-15');

-- Option 1:
select * 
  from 
  (
    select t1.product, 
           t1.shipdate, 
           (
            select max(t2.shipdate)
              from orders t2
             where t1.product = t2.product
               and t1.shipdate > t2.shipdate
           ) as lastshipped
      from orders t1
  )
where lastshipped is not null
order
   by product,
      shipDate;

-- Option 2:

select product,
       shipdate,
       max(any_earlier_ship_date) as last_ship_date
  from (
        select t1.product, 
               t1.shipdate, 
               t2.shipdate as any_earlier_ship_date
          from orders t1
         inner 
          join orders t2 
            on t1.product = t2.product
           and t2.shipdate < t1.shipdate
       )
 group
    by product,
       shipDate
 order
    by product,
       shipDate
```